# Is Dependency Injection a must in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am currently viewing multiple tutorials (and reading books) to start working with ASP.NET MVC.

I see that ninject (or similar) is widely used to implement Dependency injection and from what i understood the main issue here is resource allocation from the classes i need.

We want to be sure  for example that we have only one instance of the repo object.

I need to learn first things first so i am interested in knowing how i would create an ASP.NET MVC without using DI techniques and still be correct as far as my object resources are concerned

More info:

I have made some winforms applications. These apps where using a Business Layer DLL (BLL). This BLL had access to my DAL DLL (plain ADO.NET). they are working quite well..

No i want to use the SAME BLL to MVC apps.

With injection or not?

Without injection implementation?

Do i just create the BLL object in my controller constructor and that's all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't require you to use dependency injection at all. It will work perfectly fine if all of your controllers have default constructors. On the other hand, you will be responsible for creating the objects and managing their lifetimes. If you need to have one repository object for the application, you have to manually implement its lifecycle(using a static variable or Singleton pattern).

If you care about testing, using dependency injection will certainly help you to design more testable and reusable objects. You can easily replace the dependencies with test doubles in your test code and let DI container inject the real implementations in the runtime.

If you are sure about not using it, then make sure all of your controllers have default constructors. You don't need any configuration.

Comment: So if i go without DI: I create my BusinessLayer Object in the constructor of my controller? And then, when the page load finishes the object is disposed or i hav eto do something else? I know have 2 layer DLLs. One is my DAL (ADO.NET) and one is my business layer accesing the DAL. I want to create MVC app that communicates only with the BLL...

Comment: Yes, you have to new up the dependencies in your controller constructor. A controller object lives for the lifetime of the request, so if there is no other object holding a reference to it,  garbage collecter will take care of those. Do you have some dependencies that should be manually disposed? (implementing IDisposable)

Comment: Got it. No i dont have any

Comment: @e4rthdog Keep in mind newing up the dependencies in the controller constructor will create new objects on every request. You have to manually implement singleton life cycle whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection is not a requirement for using ASP.net MVC. You can definitely build an MVC app without it.

Where it will come in handy is if you want to perform unit testing on your application. If you would like to unit test an action in a controller, if you have DI set up, then you can mock your dependencies that are included in the controller constructor (that DI takes care of when the app is running) and set up responses to return when they are called by the Action.

This is much harder and impractical (if not impossible) to do if you are not using Dependency Injection. In such a case, if you want to use Unit Testing, it will be very hard to write pure unit tests of your Actions, since you will have no easy way to mock your service and data access layers for your tests.

And as you wrote, the DI layer will also enable you to ensure things like having only one instance of the repository objects that you are injecting, etc.